# Java CORBA Client Disconnects Immediately

Tags: java, corba

I have built a Java CORBA application that subscribes to an event server.  The application connects to and narrows on the context just fine, but as soon as an event is sent to the client, it breaks with the error below.  Please advise.

```
2010/04/25!13.00.00!E00555!enserver!EventServiceIF_i.cpp!655!PID(7390)!enserver - e._info=system exception, ID 'IDL:omg.org/CORBA/TRANSIENT:1.0'
TAO exception, minor code = 54410093 (invocation connect failed; ECONNRESET), completed = NO
```

EDIT:
Please note, this only happens when running on some machines.  It works on some, but not others.  Even on the same platform (I've tried Windows XP/7 and CentOS linux)  Some work, some don't...

Here is the WireShark output...looks like the working PC is much more interactive with the network compared to the non-working PC.
**Working PC**

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
     62 28.837255   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      50169 > 23120 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=8
     63 28.907068   fe80::5de0:8d21:937e:c649 ff02::1:3             LLMNR    Standard query A isatap
     64 28.907166   10.10.10.209          224.0.0.252           LLMNR    Standard query A isatap
     65 29.107259   10.10.10.209          10.255.255.255        NBNS     Name query NB ISATAP<00>
     66 29.227000   10.10.10.250          10.10.10.209          TCP      23120 > 50169 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=32768 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=0
     67 29.227032   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      50169 > 23120 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=66560 Len=0
     68 29.238063   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          GIOP     GIOP 1.1 Request s=326 id=5 (two-way): op=logon
     69 29.291765   10.10.10.250          10.10.10.209          GIOP     GIOP 1.1 Reply s=420 id=5: No Exception
     70 29.301395   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          GIOP     GIOP 1.1 Request s=369 id=6 (two-way): op=registerEventStat
     71 29.348275   10.10.10.250          10.10.10.209          GIOP     GIOP 1.1 Reply s=60 id=6: No Exception
     72 29.405250   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      50170 > telnet [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=8
     73 29.446055   10.10.10.250          10.10.10.209          TCP      telnet > 50170 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=32768 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=0
     74 29.446128   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      50170 > telnet [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=66560 Len=0
     75 29.452021   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TELNET   Telnet Data ...
     76 29.483537   10.10.10.250          10.10.10.209          TELNET   Telnet Data ...
     77 29.483651   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TELNET   Telnet Data ...
     78 29.523463   10.10.10.250          10.10.10.209          TCP      telnet > 50170 [ACK] Seq=4 Ack=5 Win=32768 Len=0
     79 29.554954   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      50169 > 23120 [ACK] Seq=720 Ack=505 Win=66048 Len=0
```

**Non-working PC**

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
      1 0.000000    10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      64161 > 23120 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=8
      2 2.999847    10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      64161 > 23120 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=8
      3 4.540773    Cisco_3c:78:00        Cisco-Li_55:87:72     ARP      Who has 10.0.0.1?  Tell 10.10.10.209
      4 4.540843    Cisco-Li_55:87:72     Cisco_3c:78:00        ARP      10.0.0.1 is at 00:1a:70:55:87:72
      5 8.992284    10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      64161 > 23120 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260
```

Comment: Did you check if there is a networking problem like a firewall that is configured differently on different machines? Can you establish a network connection manually? And what did you mean when you wrote "the application narrows and logs on just fine"?

Comment: Is it possible to produce and post a minimal example that exhibits the problem you are describing?

Comment: Firewalls, etc are all the same for the machines.  I connect the two machines on a regular basis whether it be RDP or SSH.  Still baffled...

Answer (score 1):

The [man page for recv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recv) states that you get a **ECONNRESET** when the other side closed the connection (for whatever reason).

```
ECONNRESET
  A connection was forcibly closed by a peer.
```

It looks like the connection is severed (for some reason) by the other side.
Could it be that the machine that does not work blocks connections (like malware protection)?